Error when upgrading Mageto 2.4.3 to 2.4.6
I'm trying to upgrade my Magento to 2.4.6 from 2.4.3.
I'm getting these errors, not sure what to do. Is there anyone who can help me?
 Problem 1
- zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.5, ..., 2.7.7] require php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.5, ..., 2.7.7] require php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- zendframework/zend-soap[2.5.2, ..., 2.6.0] require php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.8, ..., 2.7.9] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0, ..., 2.8.0] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.6.0, ..., 3.11.0] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.12.0, ..., 3.13.0] require php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-escaper 2.10.0 require php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-di[3.7.0, ..., 3.9.1] require php >=7.4, <8.2 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.6].
- magento/magento2-base 2.4.6 requires laminas/laminas-di ^3.7 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-di[3.7.0, ..., 3.14.0].
- laminas/laminas-di[3.13.0, ..., 3.14.0] require laminas/laminas-stdlib ^3.18.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.18.0, 3.19.0].
- Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-stdlib 3.19.0 (conflict analysis result)
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 requires magento/magento2-base 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.4.6].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 requires magento/framework 103.0.6 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.6].
- Root composer.json requires bambora/module-payment-magento2 ^2.3 -> satisfiable by bambora/module-payment-magento2[2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.4, 2.3.5].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.13 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.13 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.13].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.12 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.12 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.12].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.11 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.11 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.11].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.10 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.10 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.10].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.9 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.9 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.9].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.8 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.8 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.8].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.7 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.7].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.6 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.6].
- zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.8, ..., 2.4.13] require zendframework/zend-escaper ~2.4.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-escaper[2.4.0, ..., 2.4.13].
- zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.7 requires zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-escaper[2.4.7].
- zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.6 requires zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-escaper[2.4.6].
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.13.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.7.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.6.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.5.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.4.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.3.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.2.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.1.
- laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] conflict with zendframework/zend-escaper 2.4.0.
- magento/framework[103.0.6, ..., 103.0.6-p5] require laminas/laminas-escaper ^2.10 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-escaper[2.10.0, 2.11.0, 2.12.0, 2.13.0].
- Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-escaper 2.13.0 (conflict analysis result)
- bambora/module-payment-magento2[2.3.1, ..., 2.3.5] require zendframework/zend-soap ^2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.4.6, ..., 2.8.0].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.5.0 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.5.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.5.1 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.5 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.5.0, ..., 2.7.9], zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.5.0, ..., 2.7.7].
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.14.0, ..., 3.16.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.7.4.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.14.0, ..., 3.16.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.6.0.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.14.0, ..., 3.16.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.5.2.
- laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.14.0, ..., 3.16.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.5.1.
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.5.0, ..., 2.7.9, 3.0.0, ..., 3.19.0].
- laminas/laminas-di[3.10.0, ..., 3.12.0] require laminas/laminas-stdlib ^3.6 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.6.0, ..., 3.19.0].
- Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.17.0] | install one of zendframework/zend-soap[2.4.6, ..., 2.4.13] (conflict analysis result)

composer.json
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.2",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.6",
    "composer/composer": "^1.9 || ^2.0",
    "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "1.0.28",
    "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.4.5",
    "amasty/module-advanced-permissions": "^1.6",
    "snowdog/module-menu": "^2.18",
    "amasty/base": "^1.12",
    "bambora/module-payment-magento2": "^2.3",
    "klarna/m2-checkout": "^9.3",
    "hyva-themes/magento2-default-theme": "^1.3",
    "laminas/laminas-dom": "^2.7",
    "hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-widgets": "^1.0",
    "hyva-themes/magento2-cms-tailwind-jit": "^1.1",
    "amasty/module-hide-price-subscription-pack": "^1.7",
    "amasty/module-elastic-search-subscription-package-pro": "^2.3",
    "amasty/module-elastic-search-hyva-compatibility": "^1.0",
    "amasty/module-shopby-subscription-package-pro": "^3.1",
    "amasty/module-shop-by-brand-hyva-compatibility": "^1.0",
    "amasty/module-xsearch-hyva-compatibility": "^1.1",
    "amasty/module-product-parts-finder-subscription-pack": "^1.13",
    "amasty/module-product-parts-finder-hyva": "^1.0",
    "amasty/module-blog-pro-subscription-package": "^2.13",
    "amasty/module-blog-hyva": "^1.1",
    "amasty/module-improved-sorting-subscription-package": "^2.14",
    "amasty/module-sorting-hyva-compatibility": "^1.0",
    "amasty/module-product-labels-subscription-pack": "^2.3",
    "amasty/module-product-labels-hyva": "^2.0",
    "amasty/module-product-feed-subscription-package": "^2.9",
    "amasty/module-custom-forms-lite-subscription-package": "^1.21",
    "amasty/module-custom-form-hyva": "^1.1",
    "amasty/module-customer-attributes-subscription-package-lite": "^2.5",
    "amasty/module-shipping-rules-subscription-package": "^2.11",
    "amasty/module-pdf-customizer-subscription-package": "^1.5",
    "amasty/module-product-attachments-subscription-package": "^3.2",
    "amasty/module-special-promotions-subscription-package-lite": "^2.14",
    "amasty/module-mage24fix": "^1.0",
    "amasty/module-grouped-options": "^1.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"repositories": {
    "private-packagist": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://hyva-themes.repo.packagist.com/rodin-etailhandel-no/"
    },
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "amasty": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": true,
        "magento/inventory-composer-installer": true,
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true
    }
}

}

please share your composer.json file.

In you composer trace :
- zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.5, ..., 2.7.7] require php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.

Means that the package zendframework/zend-stdlib requires a version of PHP doesn't matching with your current PHP version 8.2.20. Ok, but who needs this package ?
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.5.0 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.5.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2].
- zendframework/zend-soap 2.5.1 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.5 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.5.0, ..., 2.7.9], zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.5.0, ..., 2.7.7].

Ok, so it is zendframework/zend-soap package which requires it. But can you get rid of it ? Not exactly because...
- bambora/module-payment-magento2[2.3.1, ..., 2.3.5] require zendframework/zend-soap ^2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.4.6, ..., 2.8.0].

... because bambora/module-payment-magento2 requires zendframework/zend-soap package. But, good news ! The bambora/module-payment-magento2 package is in your composer.json requirements meaning we can do something about its version and maybe its dependency as zend-soap.
Good news too, bambora package is free and available on Github, let's drop an eye on dependencies along with versions :

until 2.3.8: dependency to "zendframework/zend-soap": "^2.4.6"
between 2.4.0 and 3.0.2: dependency to "laminas/laminas-soap": "^2.9"
From 3.1.0 : dependency to these packages have been removed

Ok, what could you do ?
You could update Bambora package. But based on your logs you have access only to versions available on the Adobe Market Place. So two ways goes down from there :

Safety first : update to the nearest version available (3.0.1) and thoroughly check for regression. If everything looks fine you're good ! Or maybe you feel lucky and would go to second choice then ?
You feel lucky : update to the newest (currently 3.1.1) version and thoroughly check everything.

The nearest version available is often the safest because of the gap between your current version code and the one you want to update to. But sometimes, it's just too much precautions. To fix your mind, I advise you to read realease notes and try to find out what could be a breaking change.
Just a final note : even if you manage to fix this issue, you can fall in an other composer ones. Doesn't mean you didn't solve this one. I wish you good luck in your update, adventurer :)

This is due to the different PHP version. You can see that the Magento 2.4.3 supports PHP 7.4, while Magento 2.4.6 supports PHP 8.1 and 8.2. There are no buffers between them. When you upgrade directly from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6, it will cause some old packages cannot meet the PHP requirements. As they're still sticking with the old requirements, they think the new PHP version cannot meet the system requirements and thus block your installation.
To solve this problem, you can remove the old vendor folder first, then run the following command:
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update

It will update all the dependencies too. Hope it can solve your peoblem.
Always backup the composer.json before upgrade.

Thank you for your answer. Will this delete everything from my Vendor folder? will 3rd party modules in the Vendor folder be deleted?

No, if you need to do so, you have to run rm command manually

Not sure if I understand you. Should I go into Filezilla Eg. remove the Vendor folder and then run the composer command? Not sure if i understand you

Hi, I removed the zendframework from the vendor file but still have the issue. Is that what you meant or do you mean that i need to remove the whole Vendor file itself?

It looks like the dependencies have issue. So I need to see how the composer.json looks

I have added the composer.json is under the error message

Try to remove the dependencies by this command: rm -rf vendor;composer install; .
